# Adjusting backlight via cron?

Tags: brightness

So if I run 'xbacklight -70' on my ubuntu machine, this dims the brightness to a good level (it always boots up with 100% brightness). What is the best way to automate this? I suppose I could create a bash script to do it and then set it up in cron with a @reboot flag? If so, would would I require to put in the script to run it at the right runtime level or user environment etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as though it might be simpler to put it in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, unless you’re particularly concerned with how the system looks between when you (re)boot and when you login.

Comment: Woah. Very nice! :)